# How to get placemark icons from kml file in MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, kml

In my GIS app, i want to give custom icons to my pins/locations.In fact I want to utilize the icons whose links are in the kml (I get the placemarks from that kml file).How to "read" this information from the kml file?I am using Apple's KMLViewer. An example from the kml:

```
<Placemark>
     <name>ATM</name>
     <description>.........Info..........</description><Style>
    <IconStyle>
        <Icon>
            <href>http://www.*****.com/images/categories/atm.png</href>
        </Icon>
    </IconStyle>        
</Style><Point><coordinates>19.8167932033539,41.3254571132609</coordinates></Point></Placemark>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KMLViewer uses `NSXMLParser` to parse the KML file as it is a valid formatted XML format. First study well `NSXMLParser` and how to implement its delegate to extract the data from the XML. KMLViewer does this as well in KMLParser.m but does not implement the saving of `IconStyle` element. However it should be not very difficult (and a very good study!) to extend

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
                                        namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
                                       qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
                                          attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

method of KMLParser and add a new handler for `IconStyle`. You will have to extend `KMLStyle` class adding support for placemark icons. Then when you've got the url of the icon, it should be easy to feed it to mapkit instead of the default icon. Good luck!

Comment: You're right,in fact I've already extended KMLParser and added a new handler for IconStyle, as you said.All of this done, and already tested and proved that the icon URL was being read OK.My problem is passing it to mapkit.I am using a custom class PlacemarkAnnotation, which has a title,subtitle,coordinates and also an `icon` attribute, that is the string which holds the image name of the icon, let's say `atm.png`.The problem is that in KMLParser i get these values (using NSLog), but when it come to my mapview, I get NULL. ????????

Comment: I don't know mapKit API that well, maybe it'd be worth to open another question?

Comment: show us your `PlacemarkAnnotation` implementation. perhaps the mistake is in there?